# Manually specify POST request body in spring boot swagger

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I wrote the piece of code below:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/process", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ApiOperation(value = "Get process with given ID", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        response = ProcessType.class)
public ResponseEntity<ProcessType> createProcessType(
        @RequestBody
        @DTO(ProcessTypeDto.class) ProcessType processType
) {
    log.info("POST called on /process");

    ProcessType processTypeResult;
...
...
}
```

which works great. But my problem is with swagger. I made a custom annotation `@DTO` which automatically maps one class to another. But, swagger sees my `ProcessType` request body and shows examples in the UI of that class rather than `ProcessTypeDto`. If I delete what swagger shows and POST `ProcessTypeDto` the code works I would just like swagger to show `ProcessTypeDto` as the default example for this endpoint as it would break codegen.

Is there a way to manually specify what request body I would like from swaggers POV overriding what my`@Requestbody` is?

Comment: Do any of the Swagger annotations (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations-1.5.X) help? @ApiParam, @ApiImplicitParam?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you are not lucky so far, it will be released in version 2.0

here is what you are lookin for https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations#requestbody

or at least you can start using a release candidate 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger/swagger-core